# Command similar to ascii for ascii extended and/or for unicode?

Tags: command-line, unicode, software-rec, character-encoding, ascii

`ascii` command in Linux is fast and great. It allows us to search for a character or for a code point and returns all relevant results for a given search. Is there something similar for ASCII extended (e.g.: ISO-8859-1) and/or for Unicode characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`unicode`](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/%7Egarabik/software/unicode/) tool provides similar functionality to `ascii`:

```
$ unicode -d ..255
          .0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 .A .B .C .D .E .F 
     000.                                                 
     001.                                                 
     002.     !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  / 
     003.  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ? 
     004.  @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O 
     005.  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _ 
     006.  `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o 
     007.  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~    
     008.                                                 
     009.                                                 
     00A.     ¡  ¢  £  ¤  ¥  ¦  §  ¨  ©  ª  «  ¬    ®  ¯ 
     00B.  °  ±  ²  ³  ´  µ  ¶  ·  ¸  ¹  º  »  ¼  ½  ¾  ¿ 
     00C.  À  Á  Â  Ã  Ä  Å  Æ  Ç  È  É  Ê  Ë  Ì  Í  Î  Ï 
     00D.  Ð  Ñ  Ò  Ó  Ô  Õ  Ö  ×  Ø  Ù  Ú  Û  Ü  Ý  Þ  ß 
     00E.  à  á  â  ã  ä  å  æ  ç  è  é  ê  ë  ì  í  î  ï 
     00F.  ð  ñ  ò  ó  ô  õ  ö  ÷  ø  ù  ú  û  ü  ý  þ  ÿ
```

It can be used to map other code pages (see its `--fromcp` option):

```
$ unicode --fcp cp437 -d 200
U+255A BOX DRAWINGS DOUBLE UP AND RIGHT
UTF-8: e2 95 9a UTF-16BE: 255a Decimal: &#9562; Octal: \022532
╚
Category: So (Symbol, Other); East Asian width: A (ambiguous)
Unicode block: 2500..257F; Box Drawing
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

It can also be used to search for characters by name:

```
$ unicode acute
U+00B4 ACUTE ACCENT
UTF-8: c2 b4 UTF-16BE: 00b4 Decimal: &#180; Octal: \0264
´
Category: Sk (Symbol, Modifier); East Asian width: A (ambiguous)
Unicode block: 0080..00FF; Latin-1 Supplement
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)

Decomposition: <compat> 0020 0301

U+00C1 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
UTF-8: c3 81 UTF-16BE: 00c1 Decimal: &#193; Octal: \0301
Á (á)
Lowercase: 00E1
Category: Lu (Letter, Uppercase); East Asian width: N (neutral)
Unicode block: 0080..00FF; Latin-1 Supplement
Bidi: L (Left-to-Right)

Decomposition: 0041 0301
…
```